# Write Context Parameters to Database - Talend Administrative Console

Tags: talend

Does anyone know how to write context parameter values directly to the talend db?

Answer (score 1):

The component tContextDump creates a data flow of your context, where each row is a key/value pair.  You can write that data flow anywhere you want, for example to a database, using any of the tDBOutput components.  To load your job's context from such a database table (or from any other source), you can use tContextLoad in your job, or you can use the "implicit context load" feature, either at the job level or at the project level.  It allows your jobs to get their context parameters from another source, rather than the default property file mechanism.

Not sure what you mean by "the talend db" in your question.  The Talend Administration Center (TAC) does have a DB of its own, and if you use Talend's scheduling capabilities, then you will be able to store context values for your job as well, which will override anything that you put into your job in the studio.  These context values would then be stored in "the talend db", but this doesn't have anything to do with the discussion above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **context.put(key,value)** to put value in context and **context.get(key)** to get the value anywhere in a job.